# Can a compiler optimize multiple same function calls

Tags: c++, function, optimization

There are tons of questions and good answers concerning compiler optimization about "redundant function calls" on SO (I won't post links), however, I could not find anything on *multiple same* function calls on SO.

Say I have a code snippet like this:

```
void fairlyComplexFunction(const double &angle)
{
    //do stuff and call "sin(angle)" very often in here
}
```

Calling `sin(angle)` is a *fairly expensive* operation and since `angle` is a const within the scope of `fairlyComplexFunction` every call of the sine will end up with the same result so only calling it once would be a better approach:

```
void fairlyComplexFunction(const double &angle)
{
    const double sineOfAngle = sin(angle);
    //do stuff and use sineOfAngle very often in here
}
```

Is a compiler in any way able to detect things like these and optimize this for me or is the second example a better approach?

Comment: Compile it and look at the output yourself?

Comment: @KerrekSB First, I am really not that skilled at looking at and understanding assembly language. Also, just because when I compile it and it doesn't work, wouldn't mean that maybe other compilers won't be able to do it.

Comment: In principle, if the compiler can be sure that the function in question is a *pure* function (free of side effects, and the only thing effecting its output is its input,) then it can trivially eliminate the multiple calls. However, proving that a function is pure is not always easy or trivial in C++.

Comment: @yzt In this case, sin(x) is indeed a pure function, so I guess that it "could work in principle"?

Comment: @phil13131: Not only is a pure function, but it's a function supplied by the implementation. That's not just a "could work in principle" , I'd actually expect it. I even expect calls to `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` to be merged, even though those aren't the same functions (!)

Comment: @MSalters That's interesting to know. But how can calls to sin(x) and cos(x) be merged? If the angle is the same?

Comment: @phil13131: They share a lot of code, for instance to determine in which quadrant the angle lies. Those common bits can be merged.

Comment: `double S= sin(Angle)` can save you a lot of typing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already stated in the comment, a compiler may be able to optimize such thing if it can detect that the called function is a *pure function* (no side effects, no i/o, ...).

A small example (https://godbolt.org/g/2b3Vgg) with g++:

```
#include <cmath>

extern double g (double);

template <double (*F) (double)>
double f1 (double angle) {
  double x = 3 * F(angle) + F(angle);
  double y = F(angle) + F(angle) * F(angle);
  return x + y * F(angle);
}

template double f1<sin> (double);
template double f1<g> (double);
```

In `f1` you have multiple calls to the `F` function, and two instanciations:

- One with `std::sin` - Which should be considered a pure function by any sane compiler.
- One with an `extern` function which cannot be considered a pure function.

If you look at the generated assembly*:

```
double f1<&sin>(double):
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    sin
        ...
        ret

double f1<&(g(double))>(double):
        subq    $40, %rsp
        movsd   %xmm0, (%rsp)
        call    g(double)
        movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)
        movsd   (%rsp), %xmm0
        call    g(double)
        movsd   8(%rsp), %xmm1
        mulsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
        ...
        call    g(double)
        movsd   %xmm0, 16(%rsp)
        movsd   (%rsp), %xmm0
        call    g(double)
        movsd   %xmm0, 24(%rsp)
        movsd   (%rsp), %xmm0
        call    g(double)
        mulsd   24(%rsp), %xmm0
        movsd   16(%rsp), %xmm2
        ...
        call    g(double)
        mulsd   16(%rsp), %xmm0
        addsd   8(%rsp), %xmm0
        ...
```

You see that in the instantiation with `sin`, g++ only do one function call (`call sin`) while in the instantiation with `g`, you have 6 calls.

So **yes**, the compiler may do some optimization regarding multiple calls to *pure function* but I would not rely on it** and use an explicit intermediate variable as in your second example.

** I removed most of the generated instructions but all the `call` instructions are shown.*

*** `clang` does not optimize this even with `-O3` (but it does with `-ffast-math`).*

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a really thorough answer. I find it interestig that this is not optimized using -O3 but you need -ffast-math for it, since that should be redundant. Also it is tricky that the user "has to know this" and might end up with not fully optimized code...

Comment: @phil13131: There's a somewhat theoretical concern that the rounding mode might change between two calls, which would make the function actually impure. With `-ffast-math` the compielr can disregard rounding mode changes.

Answer (score 2):

It can optimise it if it can prove that `sin` has no side effects whatsoever.

But even if it can, your second version makes it clear both to the reader and yourself that all the code *should* use the same value and that none of the uses is a bug; there's less room for both error and uncertainty.